# Smart UV Unwrap of 32000 objects? Single core used?

Tags: python

I have a scene with over 32000 objects I want to smart UV unwrap (each as individual objects). All objects are very basic, most cuboid. I left the Smart UV project (select all SPACE then selecting smart UV project, streth to UV bounds unchecked) running on this and Blender was still not responding 24 hours later. blender process:CPU 7%, memory at 1.4GB, disk usage nothing. I assume the script was still running, but hard to be sure with the 'not responding' in the window. Would I be right in assuming that the script is python and that it won't use more than one core? I'm finding it difficult to estimate how long it should take on so many objects and if there is a faster ways to achieve this by utilizing all 8 cores? Blend file itself is 159MB and I have set this to manually 8 threads rather than leaving it on auto and I still only get 7% CPU utilization.

Comment: Though it is hard to say for sure without knowing more, i have a feeling there is a better way to achieve your goal here than putting a texture on 32000 individual objects. I'd advise telling us what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Kim, I'm building a city to import into Unreal Engine. I have to apply Smart UV Project to all of the buildings (cuboids) so that textures can be applied. This is one of thirty area sections, though most will not be as object dense as this one. The idea is to be able to apply a generic stone texture to all, but to be able to un-group them and apply individual textures to individual buildings as needed. I've found that I can select objects in groups (key B) and work my way through section by section, and it seems disproportionately faster than selecting all and setting Smart UV project off.

Comment: Welp, yep - there may be no way around that. But, it is probably good you said that, someone else who knows more may have tips for you.

Comment: Yes, they may be no way around it, thanks anyway. At least I know now that something was definitely wrong with doing a select all and applying it to everything in one go. I'm 80% done applying the smart UV project in by selecting regions at a time and it took maybe a couple of hours. At least someone else may appreciate the workaround if they need to do something similar :-)